# arduinoのplayer_objifスケッチによるspresenseのハイレゾ再生ができない

Tags: spresense

arduinoのスケッチplayer_objifにて96kHzサンプリングレートの音源を再生しようとしたのですが、再生できませんでした。
再生にあたっては以下の記述を↓に変更しています。
音源は0kから48kに5秒で遷移するアップチャープ信号を再生しましたが、10秒ほどの時間を要して0kから12kほどまで遷移して終了します。（Main player File End!は呼ばれる）
player_hiresでは再生できましたが、player_objifで使われるオブジェクトインタフェース層によるプログラムでは動かないのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
theMixer->setRenderingClkMode(OUTPUTMIXER_RNDCLK_NORMAL);
↓
theMixer->setRenderingClkMode(OUTPUTMIXER_RNDCLK_HIRESO);

thePlayer->init(MediaPlayer::Player0, AS_CODECTYPE_MP3, "/mnt/sd0/BIN", AS_SAMPLINGRATE_48000, AS_CHANNEL_STEREO);
↓
thePlayer->init(MediaPlayer::Player0, AS_CODECTYPE_WAV, "/mnt/sd0/BIN", AS_SAMPLINGRATE_192000, AS_CHANNEL_MONO);

myFile = theSD.open("Sound.mp3");
↓
myFile = theSD.open("Sound.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

質問を見たところでのコメントなんですが、
「96kHzサンプリングレートの音源を再生」というところで、96kHzサンプリングのWAVファイルを

thePlayer->init(MediaPlayer::Player0, AS_CODECTYPE_WAV, "/mnt/sd0/BIN", AS_SAMPLINGRATE_192000, AS_CHANNEL_MONO);

で、192kHzのサンプリングで再生すると、どちらかというと、倍速になってしまい、
5秒が2.5秒になって、周波数が上がる方向ですが、実際の挙動は、逆なので、
再生が48KHzになっている感じでしょうか。

また、チャンネルが異なる（Stereoをmonoで再生など）と、LRの並びを同一チャンネルで再生するので、音声が2倍に伸びてしまうことがありました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
一応、96kHzサンプリングの音源で192kHzでのplay_hires.inoでの再生は可能ということを確認していますが、よくよく考えるとおかしいので再確認してみます。
再生が48kHzになっている可能性もあるのですが、結局どうすればよいのかよくわかっていません。
音源はモノラルで再生デバイスもモノラルであることは確認しています。
再生・録音環境や音源は同じなので、原因があるとしたらやはりコード内部ということだと考えています。

Answer (score 0):

いろいろやってみてわかりました。
おっしゃる通り、上記のコードでは、結局、48kHzの出力になってハイレゾ出力できないようです。

そこで、SDKのコードなどを眺めてみて気が付きました。
おそらく、
theMixer->setRenderingClkMode(OUTPUTMIXER_RNDCLK_HIRESO);
を呼ぶタイミングを変更すると良いようです。

下記のように、beginの前に、こちらを呼ぶと、

theMixer->setRenderingClkMode(OUTPUTMIXER_RNDCLK_HIRESO);

thePlayer->begin();
theMixer->begin();

このコードでは、ハイレゾの再生ができました。